# Curb gem: How do I get the body as UTF-8?

Tags: ruby, curb

I'm using the Curb gem (https://github.com/taf2/curb) to get the HTML of a page that has special characters:

```
http = Curl.get("http://www.baidu.com/")
puts http.body_str
```

`http.body_str.encoding` is ASCII-8BIT. How do get the the `body_str` as UTF-8 without having to convert it after the fact?

Comment: `http = Curl.get("http://www.baidu.com/", {:encoding => "utf-8"})
 puts http.body_str` seems it works .

Comment: @Vinay When I run that, `http.body_str` doesn't show any special characters, and when I call `http_body_str.encoding` it's ASCII-8BIT, not UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Curl::Easy.encoding`. http://curb.rubyforge.org/classes/Curl/Easy.html#M000035

Comment: I just tried this, and it seems my encoding is not UTF-8 still.

`2.1.2 :192 >   c = Curl::Easy.new("http://www.baidu.com")
 => #<Curl::Easy http://www.baidu.com>
2.1.2 :193 > c.encoding = 'utf-8'
 => "utf-8"
2.1.2 :194 > c.perform
 => true
2.1.2 :195 > c.body_str.encoding
 => #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>```

Comment: It's curb problem, github.com/vcr/vcr/issues/150 
Not yet to solve. you only can completed again to encoding.